# What determines DZ gear score bracket?

Tags: the-division

Patch 1.2 has introduced 200+ Gear Score bracket in Dark Zone. 
To my surprise I'm in that bracket, even though my displayed Gear Score is 191.

What exactly determines which bracket are you assigned to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have **any** items that exceed 201 gear level you will find yourself in the 201+ bracket, whether the gear is equipped, in your inventory, or in your stash.  This is true even if your average gear score is below 201.

For example, when I tested this earlier today my gear score was 196.  At that time I had a 214 holster and a 204 sub-machine gun.  I entered the Dark Zone numerous times from checkpoints in Dark Zone 1, Dark Zone 3, Dark Zone 5, and Dark Zone 6.  Each time I was in the DZ 201+ bracket.  Placing my gun and holster in the stash did not change which bracket I was assigned to.

Comment: I learned that the stash contributes to your Dark Zone bracket by watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpJcKT1RUWU)

Comment: Though im not completely sure why teh stash affects it, It certainly makes sense to take into account items in your inventory. Prevents you from just equiping low rating gear to get into lower ranking zones, and then hot swapping on the higher gear and going over the limit. Its easier and safer to just never let you in.

Comment: @timelord64   182 mk17 and 182 magnum revolver

Comment: @Timelord64 I picked up a 204 shotgun and a 204 assault rifle tonight in the dark zone.

Comment: My point is, if you drop your 204 gun, but you still have another 204 gun equipped, you still retain your 204 gun average. As of the same patch, your gun gear score is automatically 3x your highest gun, in order to combat "voluntary gear score reductions". I thought that might have gone into your findings, but if the droped gun was your highest, it would not have in the way that i describe.

Comment: This is part of the change to the DZ to stop people being able to equip low level weapons to change their DZ bracket.

Comment: GS for weapons isn't simply averaged anymore.  They now only count your highest-GS weapon (across stash and inventory) plus the six armor pieces.   The GS is the total of those divided by seven.

Comment: "If you have *any* items that exceed 201 gear level you will find yourself in the 201+ bracket." Are you sure about this? It used to average the best gear score in each category across inventory and stash, but you could still enter a lower bracket if you only had one or two items of a higher level due to averaging. It would suck to have all 163 items and get thrown into 201+ as soon as you get your first 204 item!